PowerBi with Data Lake and Access keys in Azure Key Vault
Requirement: I'm looking for a way to link my Power BI that uses a data lake as a data source based on environment.
We want to connect our Power BI semantic model to a data lake based on environments (dev/staging/prod). The dynamic parameters should be set in a CI/CD pipeline via script. For the data lake url, this has been done successfully, but i'm struggling to setup the access keys using a service principles.
What I did:
I tried using the PowerBI API with the keys directly but with the error
$dataSourceCredentialsUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${workspaceId}/datasets/${datasetId}/Default.UpdateDatasources"
$dataSourceCredentials = @{
    dataSourceConnections = @(
        @{
            connectionDetails = @{
                url = "https://vtsonlinetestdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net"
            }
            credentialDetails = @{
                credentialType = "Key"
                credentials = @{
                    key = $clientSecret
                }
                privacyLevel = "None"
            }
        }
    )
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $dataSourceCredentialsUrl -Method Post -Body (ConvertTo-Json $dataSourceCredentials) -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers

Error: ""API is not accessible for application".
Actually i don't want to put the keys somewhere in a script but rather add some connection in M query with parameters (as used also with the data lake urls in my case) and just switch out the Azure Key Vaults based on environment.
Does anyone have an idea or better approach?

Service principal authentication is not supported for accessing My workspace (myorg).

Refer this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal?tabs=azure-portal#considerations-and-limitations for limitations for Service principal authentication

According to the docs i should use this "myorg", i think we used workspaces v2 because these are quite new, how should i check if it is "My workspace" and how would i need to adapt the api call? Thanks! :)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-datasources

Can you try including the workspace ID in the URLhttps://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{WorkspaceID}/datasets/{datasetId}/Default.UpdateDatasources and let me know if it works?

Yes,with this:
$dataSourceCredentialsUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${workspaceId}/datasets/${datasetId}/Default.UpdateDatasources"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $dataSourceCredentialsUrl -Method Post -Body (ConvertTo-Json $dataSourceCredentials) -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers
i then i get this error: i get this error:  The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Did you pass teh correct WorkspaceID?

Yes, double checked - is it possible that i have to remove the "myorg" from the uri? It wasn't in the url at least in the PowerBI Service UI
Without it i get this error:
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

You need to switch to any user interactive flow

What do you mean by that? :)

It might be a limitations? this API doesn't support Azure Data Lake storage? But handling via Parameters seems unsafe to me..

AFAIK handling via Parameters seems safe

ANy update on the issue?

Not really, i didn't know how to change the credentials via Parameters for Data lake, so i tried to use Web.Content function in PBI with M Query, which did work on PBI Desktop but lead to weird connection warnings in Power Bi Service online.. Any further ideas? Also maybe regarding usage of parameters with ADLS credentials?

Just giving this as an answer.
Since adls gen2 is not supported, need to use the Update Parameters In Group API call like mentioned  here.
Here is the sample on how to make update parameters api call.
$body = @{
    updateDetails = @(
        @{
            name = "ADLS_Connection"
            newValue = "https://<prod_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<prod_container>"
        }
    )
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method POST -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10) -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"

You need to give the name of the field you want to change in name
and updated value in the newValue.

Thanks! Where would i put the credentials to safely pass those values? :)
